# Increasing a resetting value every nth iteration in python

Tags: python

I'm working with 2d lists in python and trying to separate the lists into cells.

```
for line in board:

   self.row.append(line)

   cell_idx = 0            # Initial resetting value

   if row_idx % 3 == 0:
       cell_idx += 3       # New resetting value
```

The cell index resets for each row in the list, but I want it to reset to 3 after 3 iterations and 6 after 6 iterations until including 9.

I know I can use modulo to isolate every third process, but how do i reset to 3 when running the 4th and 5th iteration instead of 0?

edit: I realized after reading the answers that i neglected to inform that the cell_idx increments when used in the loop. I don't know why I didn't include more here it is:

```
for col_idx in range(9):

   self.col[col_idx].insert(row_idx, line[col_idx])

   # This part needs the index

   self.cell[cell_idx].insert(row_idx, line[col_idx + triple])

   if col_idx % 3 == 0:
      cell_idx += 1
```

And the cell_idx is as follows

```
add triple to list (cell_idx)0: 0 1 2
add triple to list (cell_idx)1: 0 1 2
add triple to list (cell_idx)2: 0 1 2
add triple to list (cell_idx)0: 0 1 2
add triple to list (cell_idx)1: 0 1 2
add triple to list (cell_idx)2: 0 1 2
add triple to list (cell_idx)0: 0 1 2
add triple to list (cell_idx)1: 0 1 2
add triple to list (cell_idx)2: 0 1 2

add triple to list (cell_idx)3: 3 4 5
add triple to list (cell_idx)4: 3 4 5
add triple to list (cell_idx)5: 3 4 5
add triple to list (cell_idx)3: 3 4 5
add triple to list (cell_idx)4: 3 4 5
add triple to list (cell_idx)5: 3 4 5
add triple to list (cell_idx)3: 3 4 5
add triple to list (cell_idx)4: 3 4 5
add triple to list (cell_idx)5: 3 4 5

add triple to list (cell_idx)6: 6 7 8
add triple to list (cell_idx)7: 6 7 8
add triple to list (cell_idx)8: 6 7 8
add triple to list (cell_idx)6: 6 7 8
add triple to list (cell_idx)7: 6 7 8
add triple to list (cell_idx)8: 6 7 8
add triple to list (cell_idx)6: 6 7 8
add triple to list (cell_idx)7: 6 7 8
add triple to list (cell_idx)8: 6 7 8
```

Comment: Can you give sample input and output for your problem?

Comment: Try moving line `cell_idx` before `for` loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can use integer division.  I think this is a bit cleaner than conditionally changing the state of an additional counter.

```
for i in range(12):
    cell_idx = i // 3
    print("{: >2}: {}".format(i, cell_idx))
```

Output:

```
 0:  0                                                                                                                          
 1:  0                                                                                                                          
 2:  0                                                                                                                          
 3:  1                                                                                                                          
 4:  1                                                                                                                          
 5:  1                                                                                                                          
 6:  2                                                                                                                          
 7:  2                                                                                                                          
 8:  2                                                                                                                          
 9:  3                                                                                                                          
10:  3                                                                                                                          
11:  3
```